# Manipulate values in a pandas dataframe in addiction to other values different coulmns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

im trying to manipulate specifiv values in my dataframe in addiction to other values. First I tried to do it with loop iterating over the length of the df but this is not very productive. Second idea was a .apply function but I couldnt get it work.

The Loop-Code looked like this:

```
for i in range(len(result_final)):

if result_final['drivingDirection'][i] == 1:

    if result_final['xVelocity'][i] < 0 and result_final['xAcceleration'][i] < 0:
        result_final['xVelocity'][i] = abs(result_final['xVelocity'][i])
        result_final['xAcceleration'][i] = abs(result_final['xAcceleration'][i])
        result_final['precedingXVelocity'][i] = abs(result_final['precedingXVelocity'][i])

    if result_final['xVelocity'][i] < 0 and result_final['xAcceleration'][i] > 0:
        result_final['xVelocity'][i] = abs(result_final['xVelocity'][i])
        result_final['xAcceleration'][i] = (0 - result_final['xAcceleration'][i])
        result_final['precedingXVelocity'][i] = abs(result_final['precedingXVelocity'][i])

    if result_final['xVelocity'][i] < 0 and result_final['xAcceleration'][i] == 0:
        result_final['xVelocity'][i] = abs(result_final['xVelocity'][i])
        result_final['precedingXVelocity'][i] = abs(result_final['precedingXVelocity'][i])
```

Any idea how to get that work more efficient?

Comment: It is a little too complex for me to write a full answer. But as hint, you should try to use `np.where`. It allows vectorized tests.

Comment: can you post your sample dataframes with your expected output

Comment: see answer .....

Comment: Ah got it with `np.where`. Thank you @Serge Ballesta